# response object in scrapy not complete

Tags: scrapy

Sorry if the question is stupid but I couldn't find the answer yet.

I am trying to prepare the script to extract data from a website using the "scrapy shell" command :

- Using a web browser entering the url (e.g. "http://www.testsite.com/data_to_extract"), I get the data to extract. The page contains static data + dynamic data.
- Using the command "scrapy shell http://www.testsite.com/data_to_extract" and then issuing the command ("view(response)"), I see in the web browser the static data of the page but not the dynamic data.

What I suspect is that the web server serves first the static data then fills-in the dynamic data in the page. I guess this is managed through javascript on the web page.

If my understanding is correct, what needs to happen is that scrapy needs to wait a little bit before returning the result.

Could someone help me here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Scrapy will give what you can see in browsers' "view source" command, not necessarily what you see interpreted in your browser's window. Scrapy does not understand Javascript, so not AJAX calls, no jQuery magic... So no dynamic data. You can look at network activity from your browser developer tools, and try to mimic the Javascript/AJAX calls with new Scrapy Request() to fetch aditional content but it can be difficult to imitate a real browser with Scrapy

Comment: You can also look into https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using selenium and phantomjs headless webdriver in a download handler middleware.

```
class JsDownload(object):

@check_spider_middleware
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:\phantomjs.exe')
    driver.get(request.url)
    return HtmlResponse(request.url, encoding='utf-8', body=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
```

I wanted to ability to tell different spiders which middleware to use so I implemented this wrapper:

```
def check_spider_middleware(method):
@functools.wraps(method)
def wrapper(self, request, spider):
    msg = '%%s %s middleware step' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
    if self.__class__ in spider.middleware:
        spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
        return method(self, request, spider)
    else:
        spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level=log.DEBUG)
        return None

return wrapper
```

settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'MyProj.middleware.MiddleWareModule.MiddleWareClass': 500}
```

for wrapper to work all spiders must have at minimum:

```
middleware = set([])
```

to include a middleware:

```
middleware = set([MyProj.middleware.ModuleName.ClassName])
```

You could have implemented this in a request callback (in spider) but then the http request would be happening twice. This isn't a full proof solution but it works for stuff that loads on .ready(). If you spend some time reading into selenium you can wait for specific event's to trigger before saving page source.

Another example: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs

Cheers!